# Exploding an array and putting the values in a link with the href tag the exploded part

Tags: php, html, arrays, explode

I have this basic system of displaying tags as links.

In the DB the tags are stored as tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4 etc.

I already so far have them as a links, but cant figure out how to make the tag link to its own name.

Currently:

```
$tags2 = "tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4";

$tagsInfo = "<a class='tag-buildinfo' href='search.php'>".implode("</a>, <a class='tag-buildinfo' href='search.php?st=NAME OF TAG HERE'>",explode(",",$tags2 ))."</a>";
```

What i want is to be able to explode that array and put each tag into a link that will have a href of search.php?st= and then put the name of the tag there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$tags2 = "tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4";

    // Put your tags in an array
    $tagsArray = explode(',', $tags2);

    $tagsLinksArray = array();
    foreach($tagsArray as $tag) {

        // Remove spaces
        $tagName = trim($tag);
        $tagsLinksArray[] = '<a class="tag-buildinfo" href="search.php?st='.$tagName.'">'.$tagName.'</a>';
    }

    // Join links in a string
    $tagsLinks = implode(', ', $tagsLinksArray);

    echo $tagsLinks;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tags2 = "tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4";
$tags2 = explode(',', $tags2);

for($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $tagsInfo = "<a class='tag-buildinfo' href='search.php?st=" . $tags2[$i] . "'>";
}
```

That's how you output.

When using the explode() function, a variable becomes an array and each element is separated by the separator provided in the function:

explode('separator', variable to turn into array);

http://php.net/explode/